# how to zip my services documents with angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, zip

I have these services that return documents to me. I would like to know how I can package them all in a single .zip file ?

```
 descargartodo = (data) => {
    // var idEvento2 = data;
    console.log(this.idToPass)
    const doc = this.documentoz
    if (this.idToPass > 0) {
      data = this.idToPass

      console.log(this.idToPass)
      const { idEvento: idEvento } = this.store.selectSnapshot(FORM_RESUMEN_SOL_STATE_TOKEN);    
   
          this.solicitudesService.descargarSolAgendaWord(data).subscribe(blob => {
            CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'agenda.docx');
          });
           
          this.solicitudesService.descargarReporteInvitadosWord(data).subscribe(blob => {
            CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'invitados.docx');
          });

        this.solicitudesService.descargarSolFormatoEventoPdf(data).subscribe(blob => {
          CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'formato.pdf');
        });
        
          this.solicitudesService.descargarReporteDueWord(data).subscribe(blob => {
            CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'Mapa.docx');
          });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use external lib like jszip - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip
Using this lib you can put all your files (returned from services) and zip them.